# Is AzureDevops Project Board Cumulative Flow Diagram limited to only 180 days of reporting?

Tags: azure-devops

Im trying to run an Azure Devops Project Cumulative Flow Diagram report from beginning of year until today. However, the dropdown does not allow for selecting anything above 180 days. Is this the limit? Are subscriptions limiting the number of days in the rolling period?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the limit?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

The answer is yes. This behavior is by designed. As we know, the cumulative flow diagram (also known as CFD) is one of the most advanced analytics for Lean management. It provides a concise visualization of the three most important metrics of your flow:

- **Cycle time**
- Throughput
- Work in progress

Using a CFD, you can get an idea of how long is the approximate cycle time of your tasks in just a single glance. And the number of days/weeks/months that have passed is the approximate average cycle time of your team’s assignments for the time frame.

So, CFD will be limited to a certain period.

If you have further requirement to expand this period, you could You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

> Are subscriptions limiting the number of days in the rolling period?

AFAIK, the answer is no.

Hope this helps.